# How to draw 3D sets in Mathematica given inqualities

Tags: plotting, sets

I would like to draw a 3D set ($E$) given the following conditions:

$E=\{(x, y, z)\in\mathbb R^3: x, y, z \in [0, 1], x+2y-1\leq z\}$

I have seen in the Mathematica documentation that there are several functions to draw things like that (e.g Plot3D or ParametricPlot3D). All these function does not meet my needs since I need to draw the intersection between the cube $[0, 1]^3$ and the semi-space $x, +2y-1\leq z$.

Do you know a function that can plot a set like this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check the documentation for `ImplicitRegion` and `RegionPlot3D`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
RegionPlot3D[x + 2 y - 1 <= z,
 {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Another way is

```
Graphics3D[HalfSpace[{1, 2, -1}, 1], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

Or

```
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[{{x, y, z} ∈ Cuboid[], 
    x + 2 y - 1 <= z}, {x, y, z}];
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[
   x + 2 y - 1 <= z, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}];
reg3 = ImplicitRegion[{x + 2 y - 1 <= z, 0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1, 
    0 <= z <= 1}, {x, y, z}];
reg4 = RegionIntersection[Cuboid[], 
   ImplicitRegion[x + 2 y - 1 <= z, {x, y, z}]];
reg5 = RegionIntersection[Cuboid[], HalfSpace[{1, 2, -1}, 1]];
Region[reg1, BaseStyle -> Orange]
RegionEqual[reg1, reg2, reg3, reg4, reg5]
```

> `True`

[image]